# Visual Studio Code error: (options.globals || []).reduce is not a function

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I configure eslint in the editor, from the manual https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals:

In my config, it looks like this:

```
"eslint.enable": true,
  "eslint.options": {
    "globals": {        
      "$": true,
      "moment": true
    },
...
```

With such settings, VS Code generates an error:

```
(options.globals || []).reduce is not a function
```

How to configure the global config of eslint in VS Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out, the solution was unexpected enough and found here https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/6922
Those.

It is suggested to replace the global settings object with an array, and now with this in mind, my config looks like this:

```
"eslint.enable": true,
  "eslint.options": {
    "globals": [        
      "$",
      "moment"       
    ],
...
```

I hope someone will reduce the time to find a solution to the problem.